# Django template does not output datetime

Tags: python, django

I'm currently on my way of learning some django version is 4.1.

I created a simple page which displays all objects inside a database table. Everything works as wanted, but only on my local machine.

On the remote machine only pages without any objects/models which contain at least one datetime database field work.

So my question is, how do i find out the error. From the "host" I only get the following response if I use any datetime in the template (first part always changes but the "esponse" part is always the same):

```
��esponse received from application
```

On the local machine I get a correct list of objects with their attributes. I use the same database, so all schema and data is the same.

I tried around like 3 hours now and I'm out of ideas. The /admin page also does not work on the webhost only when I visit the localhost it can display output (my guess is also datetime).

The ONLY thing I found out by now is, that if I get an object with a datetime field and I use the following code, I can get the view to render the following:

```
 obj = Example.objects.first()
 field_value = getattr(obj, 'created_at')
 return render(request, 'exam/index.html', {'test': str(field_value)})
```

this will output the Example.created_at like:

```
2022-08-16 01:09:18+00:00
```

But I'm sure there is some way to figure out why the datetime is broken only when accessed via one host and not the localhost.

Comment: Does the hosted application has the same database as your local application? (The same data in it)

Comment: Yes the settings.py file is exactly the same. So I'm also using the same mysql database. (I can see changes from one site on the other, lists work only datetime field models got the error)

Comment: What I meant is, is the data inside the database the same? For example, in your local DB you have a user called Dominik, and in the other one too?